# \mathscr undefined in TeXLive 2020

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, undefined

I recently noticed that ever since I upgraded to a TexLive 2020 installation, `\mathscr` hasn't been working in any of my documents. This is a MWE that reproduces the error on my installation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{L}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That has never worked, you need a package such as `euscript`

Comment: Did you maybe used to load a font package such as `mathrsfs` that provides a macro called `\mathscr`?

Comment: My bad -- I habitually carried that behavior over from mathjax where this would work

Comment: mathjax doesn't use tex but emulates latex math with a bunch of packages pre-loaded including amsmath and euscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has never worked, you need a package such as `euscript` (or `mathrsfs` or `stix` or several other packages which supply a `\mathscr` command).

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an addendum to David Carlisle’s correct answer.

I recommend that you use the modern toolchain with `unicode-math` if you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts if you have to.  If you load `unicode-math`, `\mathscr` will, by default, be an alias for `\mathcal`.  If you actually want to use to distinct alphabets in the same document, you can enable both with a command such as:

```
 \setmathfont[range={scr,bfscr},
              Scale=MatchUppercase,
              StylisticSet=1]{STIX Two Math}
```

Several math fonts store an alternative script or calligraphic alphabet as a stylistic set or alternative, for just this purpose, but [STIX Two Math is one of the few that documents them.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/stix2-otf/StixTwoMath.pdf)

If you are using legacy fonts, the [`mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) package is the best way to load additional math alphabets.  It offers a comprehensive selection, with font samples, and a consistent interface for features such as bold and scaling.